# I want to make my search textbox expand on mouse click and decrease when i remove the mouse

Tags: html

//textbox not animating

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
background-color:#f09;
}

.search input.search.text {
height:30px;
border:0 !important;
color:#555;
margin:0 auto;
width:200px;
transition: width 700ms,background 700ms;
-webkit-transition:width 700ms, background 700ms;
-moz-transition:width 700ms, background 700ms;
-ms-transition:width 700ms, background 700ms;
-0-transition:width 700ms, background 700ms;
box-shadow : inset 0 1px 1px #444;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #444;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #444;
-ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #444;
-o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #444;
 border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
-ms-border-radius:3px;
-o-border-radius:3px;   
}

.search input.search.text:focus{
background-color:#00FFFF;
width:450px;}

</style>
```

HTML

```
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <div class="search">
      <input class="search.text" type="text" value="&nbsp;search..."/>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

I want my textbox to expand when it gains focus and decrease when I remove focus from the textbox.

Comment: <input class="search.text" ?? change it to <input class="search text"

Comment: That worked for me ... Tanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="search text" type="text" value="&nbsp;search..."/>

<style>
.search:hover{
    width: 300px;
}
.search{
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    transition: width 2s;
     width: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the class name

```
<input class="search.text" type="text" value="&nbsp;search..."/>
```

to

```
<input class="search text" type="text" value="&nbsp;search..."/>
```

otherwise your code is working fine